# Ignore WebSocket connection in Spring Security SavedRequest

Tags: grails, spring-security, websocket, atmosphere

I have a Grails application with spring-security-core plugin and [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki) framework.

If I log out from a page that has opened a WebSocket connection, then Spring Security keeps the URL of the WebSocket connection as SavedRequest.

```
DEBUG savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache  - DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8080/formx/formX/update]
DEBUG savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache  - DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8080/formx/formX/notifications/?X-Atmosphere-Transport=close&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=b5d8fde4-d950-41fd-9b49-02e06799a36f&conversationId=988080042]
```

The first entry in the log has the correct value for SavedRequest, but somehow it is overwritten by the Atmosphere WebSocket connection.

How do I tell Spring Security to not use the Atmosphere WebSocket connection as SavedRequest?

I guess I can use some [Atmosphere Protocol Specific Header](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Understanding-the-Atmosphere-Protocol) to distinguish connections.

Comment: What about adding 'none'security on Atmosphere handler : <security:http><security:intercept-url pattern="**/X-Atmosphere-Transport**" access="none"/></security:http>

Comment: Hello, Trying to clean up unanswered. Did you solve this? Maybe you can answer your own question.

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not have solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Java config you can set the RequestMatcher - then it's easy.

In WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    HttpSessionRequestCache cache = new HttpSessionRequestCache(); //this one is used by default
    cache.setRequestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE); //change the request matcher, so it do not match your Atmosphere requests
    http.requestCache().requestCache(cache);
}
```